# Confusion on checking if a set is a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

While going through vector space problems, the biggest thing that is confusing me is how do I go about proving the closure criteria if I am only given info on a single vector, such as:

The set of vectors $ \langle a_{1},a_{2} \rangle$, where $ a_{1} + a_{2} = 0 $

Let's say for the associative law. The textbook tells me "For all $ \vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z} $ in $ V \text{, } \vec{x}+(\vec{y}+\vec{z})=(\vec{x}+\vec{y})+\vec{z}$."

But since I am only given 2 elements in a single vector, $\langle a_{1},a_{2} \rangle$ , how can I prove that? Do I need to create 2 new vectors like $\vec{b} = \langle b_{1},b_{2} \rangle$ and $\vec{c} = \langle c_{1},c_{2} \rangle$ to prove it? Or do I create another element $a_{3}$ in $\vec{a}$ like $\vec{a} = \langle a_{1},a_{2}, a_{3} \rangle$ and then perform the calculation to prove the associative law?

I am assuming I will need to create new vectors $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ since the axioms in the textbook use vector notation in all the criteria, but I just want clarification since I see people on Chegg proving it both ways and it is very confusing.

Comment: You need to consider three vectors satisfying the condition.$\langle a_1,a_2\rangle$, $\langle b_1,b_2\rangle$ and $\langle c_1,c_2\rangle$ with $a_1+a_2=b_1+b_2=c_1+c_2=0$.

Comment: Thank you GReyes. So to be clear, for any vector space, not specifically this one, I can't just take out the 2 a1 and a2 elements of the vector and check the axioms by saying like a1 + a2, I'd have to add 2 separate vectors a and b to give <a1 + b1, a2+b2> ?

Answer (score 1):

In a phrase like

> "The set of vectors ⟨a1,a2⟩, where a1+a2=0"

the numbers a1 and a2 are *dummy variables*. They refer only to things within the phrase. You could equally well write "The set of vectors ⟨x,y⟩, where x+y=0". Each time you use the phrase you replace the dummy variables with the variables you want to use.

This lets you make a statement like

> Let ⟨x1, x2⟩ and ⟨y1, y2⟩ be in the set. Then x1 + x2 = 0 and y1 + y2 = 0.

Comment: To emphasize, it would have been clearer if they’d said the set of *all* vectors … satisfying … .

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense! Much appreciated! I can't tell you how long I spent tripped up on the wording in the book...